# ternary operator in option element in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using asp.net core 2.1 and I want to use `selected option` element and set values manually in it like the code below:

```
<select>
   <option selected="@(typeCar== "Volvo" ? "selected" : string.Empty)" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option selected="@(typeCar== "Saab" ? "selected" : string.Empty)" value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="vw">VW</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

but when i wanted to use ternary operator in both of them `selected="selected"` is equal to `selected=""` So the two options are selected and apparently there is no difference between `selected="selected"` and  `selected=""`, for example when `typeCar=Volvo`view page source in browser is like below:

```
    <select>
       <option selected="selected" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option selected="" value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="vw">VW</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

and second option is selected!
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: where is your condition ?

Comment: the first option but @() is not recognized so i didn't write others it's useless.

Comment: what is your condition ? Where did you write it ?

Comment: I write it now.

Comment: Why are you not using the asp net SELECT tag helper which does this for you ?

Comment: I'm not using model it's just a simple select option. do you have any solution for my problem?

Comment: You cannot use a C# conditional expression inside your option item. You can do it outside of the option. But i suggest you use the SELECT tag helper which does the proper binding for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return null from your ternary instead of `string.Empty`. If the attribute's value is null, Razor will remove it automatically, but since you're setting it to *something*, even if it's just an empty string, it will persist.

```
<select>
    <option selected="@(typeCar== "Volvo" ? "selected" : null)" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option selected="@(typeCar== "Saab" ? "selected" : null)" value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="vw">VW</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Shyju said, you can't use ternary operator expression to create `selected` attribute like your current example does. Use either JS/jQuery expression like this example:

```
$('select').append('<option value="' + typeCar + '"' + (typeCar == 'somevalue') ? ' selected="selected"' : '') + '>' + typeCar + '</option>';
```

Or simply use `<select>` tag helper:

```
<select asp-for="TypeCar" asp-items="Model.Cars"></select>
```

which populated from a list which contains `SelectListItem`:

```
public List<SelectListItem> Cars { get; set; } = CarsList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CarName, Value = x.CarId, Selected = x.IsSelected }).ToList();
```

Further reference: [ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1)